# How can I show my canvas in a .jar file, as only the JFrame shows?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, canvas, jar

I have asked this question before, but it wasn't good enough, so I deleted it and made a new one.

I'm building a game and I want to export the game as a .jar file so I can run it on other people's computers. The only problem is, when I run the jar, an empty JFrame appears. What should at least appear is a black screen, even though I have added my Canvas to the JFrame.

I can run everything in my IDE (Eclipse), but when I put it on my desktop, nothing seems to happen. One of the solutions I pondered was to download the .jars and put them in the AppData folder of said computer, and then get the login application (which works just fine) to run the main class in the .jar using a URLClassLoader.

The only problem with that is that I don't quite understand how to use the URLClassLoader, nor am I good with using the JavaDoc either. :/

Here's a look at my main class (I have all my imports too,):

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6601282971656374659L;

    /* The version of the game, will be updates with annotation later! It also has the location to the game path! */
    public static final String version = "Version: 0.1 Alpha";
    private static final String GAME_PATH = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\[Game]";

    /* Basic integers and Dimensions for the JFrame and Canvas */
    public static final int WIDTH = 460;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 280;
    private static final int SCALE = 2;
    private final Dimension size = new Dimension((WIDTH * SCALE), (HEIGHT * SCALE));

    /* BufferedImage below is the one thing that is drawn to the screen. The pixels[] array holds the pixel data of said image. */
    private BufferedImage screen = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    public int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) screen.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    /* A Thread for running the game and two Booleans for being either in-game or in-menu. */
    private Thread thread;
    public static volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    public static volatile boolean inGame = false;

    /* Characters for determining what state the player is in, and what level is selected. (MAY CHANGE TO INT LATER!) */
    public static char state = 'N';
    public static int player_select = 0;
    public static int level_select = 0;

    /* The only non-local reference in this class. Used for creating the window. */
    JFrame frame;

    /* Imports having to do with the logic behind the game and then rendering. */
    Display display;
    UIListener listen;
    Keyboard key;
    Mouser mouse;
    Music music;

    /* The three main classes. */

    /**
     * The main constructor. It's responsible for creating the JFrame and adding this canvas to it. It also sets the level to a default selection.
     */
    public Game() {
            frame = new JFrame("Game");

            display = new Display(screen);
            key = new Keyboard(200);
            mouse = new Mouser();
            listen = new UIListener(mouse);

            setPlayer(PlayerClass.KNIGHT);
            setLevel(ClassicLevel.FLOOR_1);

            if (getLevel() == ClassicLevel.floor_1) {
                    getPlayer().setDirection(PlayerClass.NORTH);
            }

            setPreferredSize(size);
            setMaximumSize(size);
            setMinimumSize(size);
            addKeyListener(key);
            addMouseListener(mouse);

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();

            frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/Game_logo.png").getImage());
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for starting the game, the most important part. It also requests the focus of the Canvas and creates a buffer strategy.
     */
    public synchronized void begin() {
            thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            requestFocus();

            thread.start();
            isRunning = true;
    }

    /**
     * Method responsible for stopping the thread that runs the game.
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public synchronized void finish() throws InterruptedException {
            isRunning = false;
            thread.join();
    }

    /* Integers that reflect the Keyboard's movements. Should not be removed. */
    int xMove = 0, yMove = 0;

    /**
     * This method is responsible for updating the logic behind the game, i.e. Mobs, time, AI, etc.
     */
    private synchronized void tick() {
            key.checkForKeys();
            int speed = getPlayer().getSpeed();

            if (key.up) {
                    yMove -= speed;
                    getPlayer().setDirection(PlayerClass.NORTH);
            }

            if (key.down) {
                    yMove += speed;
                    getPlayer().setDirection(PlayerClass.SOUTH);
            }

            if (key.left) {
                    xMove -= speed;
                    getPlayer().setDirection(PlayerClass.WEST);
            }

            if (key.right) {
                    xMove += speed;
                    getPlayer().setDirection(PlayerClass.EAST);
            }
    }

    /* Integers responsible for the FPS and UPS. */
    public int frames = 0, updates = 0;

    /**
     * Method responsible for rendering the logic in the "update()" method to the screen.
     */
    private synchronized void render() {
            BufferStrategy buffer = this.getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics gfx = buffer.getDrawGraphics();

            final int centerY = (HEIGHT / 2) - (48 / 2);
            final int centerX = (WIDTH / 2) - (48 / 2);

            display.clear();
            getLevel().render(xMove, yMove, display);
            display.renderPlayer(getPlayer(), centerX, centerY);

            display.alignPixels(pixels);

            gfx.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            gfx.drawImage(UIRender.playerBar(getPlayer().getIcon()), 0, getHeight() - 100, 200, 100, null);

            gfx.setFont(GameGUI.gameFont());
            gfx.setColor(new Color(220, 220, 220));
            gfx.drawString(Game.version, 3, 15);

            if (key.show) {
                    key.showInfo(gfx, frames, updates);
            } else if (key.escape) {
                    UIRender.renderEscapeMenu(this);
            }

            gfx.dispose();
            buffer.show();
    }

    public final void screenShot(String filename) throws Exception {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Rectangle window = new Rectangle(frame.getX(), frame.getY(), WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(window);
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(GAME_PATH + filename));
    }

    /**
     * Method responsible for setting the state of the game. (i.e. in options, in credits, etc.)
     * 
     * @param setState
     */
    public static void setState(char setState) {
            state = setState;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the desired player for the game.
     * 
     * @param selection
     */
    public static void setPlayer(int selection) {
            player_select = selection;
    }

    /**
     * Method for returning the player that the user has selected while in the class select.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static PlayerClass getPlayer() {
            if (player_select == 1) return KnightClass.knight;
            if (player_select == 2) return WizardClass.wizard;
            if (player_select == 3) return ArcherClass.archer;

            return KnightClass.knight;
    }

    /**
     * Method responsible for setting the desired level of the user.
     * 
     * @param selection
     */
    public static void setLevel(int selection) {
            level_select = selection;
    }

    /**
     * Method used for getting the level that the user picked.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private final Level getLevel() {
            if (level_select == ClassicLevel.FLOOR_1) return ClassicLevel.floor_1;
            return SurvivalLevel.level;
    }

    /**
     * The main "run()" method; needed for any class that implements the Runnable.java interface.
     */
    public void run() {
            long pastTime = System.nanoTime(), lastSecond = System.currentTimeMillis();

            final float desig = 1_000_000_000F / 50F;
            float single = 0;

            // Remove to play actual game.
            state = 50;

            if (state != 50) {
                    //Music.playTitleMusic();
            }

            while (isRunning == true) {
                    if (state == 'N') {
                            UIRender.renderNaprav(this);
                            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSecond) > 2000) {
                                    // Wait 2 seconds and then go to the menu.
                                    lastSecond += 1000;
                                    state = 'M';
                            }
                    } else if (state == 'M') {
                            UIRender.renderMenu(this);
                            listen.listenInMenu();
                    } else if (state == 'O') {
                            UIRender.renderOptions(this);
                            listen.listenInOptions();
                    } else if (state == 'C') {
                            UIRender.renderCredits(this);
                            listen.listenInCredits();
                    } else if (state == 'S') {
                            UIRender.renderClassSelect(this);
                            listen.listenInClassSelection();
                    } else if (state == 'L') {
                            UIRender.renderLevelSelect(this);
                            listen.listenInLevelSelection();
                    } else if (state == 'Q') {
                            System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                            inGame = true;
                            // Remember to comment out the code below when state is auto-equal to 50.
                            //Music.stopTitleMusic();
                            break;
                    }
            }

            while (inGame == true) {
                    long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                    single += (currentTime - pastTime) / desig;

                    pastTime = currentTime;
                    while (single >= 1) {
                            tick();
                            updates++;
                            single--;
                    }

                    frames++;
                    render();

                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSecond) > 1000) {
                            lastSecond += 1000;
                            frame.setTitle("Game | FPS: " + frames + ", UPS: " + updates);

                            frames = 0;
                            updates = 0;
                    }
            }
    }

    /**
     * The "main()" method; needed for every Java program.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //new Login();
            Game dungeon = new Game();
            dungeon.begin();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.